# How to move cursor, insert text, etc. freely after the end of line?

Tags: normal-mode

For example, to close this "box" (the `$` signs added to show the end of lines),

```
########$
#$
# lofa$
#$
########$
```

I would have to manually edit each line to add the appropriate amount spaces, and then finish with a `#`.

---

I know there is a simple command to enable to navigate everywhere in normal mode, and I spend ca. 10-15 minutes to track it down when I need it every other month, but this time I can't find it for the life of me...

Comment: Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help you further. Otherwise maybe could you accept a solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option you are looking for is `:help 'virtualedit'`.

Once you have set it to a value that works for you, why don't you persist it into your `vimrc` so that you don't have to look it up again?

FWIW, I have it set to "block":

```
set virtualedit=block
```

but you should try the other values before using this one blindly.

Answer (score 4):

I would do:

```
set virtualedit=block
```

With this option set the block selection is allowed to select past of the end of the line.

You could then:

- `$`<kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>`4j` select the last column
- `A` switch to 'append' mode
- `#` add `#`
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> leave 'append' mode

Answer (score 2):

I would just use <kbd>CTRL-v</kbd> blockwise-visual:

- `gg`  go to start of file
- `<C-v>`  start visual selection in block mode
- `G` go to the end of file, while selection block of the first letters (#)
- `y` yank the text block (copy to register)
- `gg`  go to start of file
- `$` go to the end of line
- `p` paste the block to form nice rectangle

```
#########$
#       #$
# lofa  #$
#       #$
#########$
```